# Rack Middleware execution railscast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, middleware, rack, railscasts

To understand Rack, I was following Railscast video on [Rack Middleware](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware) and trying out the same thing in my machine. But I'm facing few issues and unable to solve.

Firstly, the Rails::Initializer.run is not in my Rails App (I'm using Rails 6), so i went through their comments in the above mentioned link and other stackoverflow comments and tried moving "ResponseTimer.rb" file to app/middleware and few other things but none of them seems to work.

All I'm getting is error like this,

`` undefined method `new' for "ResponseTimer":String (NoMethodError) ``

`Did you mean?  next`

Help me to understand what is happening and what needs to be done. TIA.

Comment: Ryan Bates burned out in 2013 and unfortunely abandoned the Railscasts project. That means that the content is a almost a decade old and almost completly irrelevant today except the episodes that cover software engineering basics (like the excellent one on [reading stack traces](http://railscasts.com/episodes/24-the-stack-trace)). Both Ruby and Rails have changed immensely and you shouldn't really expect tutorials more then a few years old to actually work.